# Conventional commit type for library version bump

Tags: python, python-poetry, conventional-commits

I'm building a library in python and wanted to know which `type` I should use -following [Conventional Commits](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/) idea- whenever I bump the version of my library in `pyproject.toml`.

This is the diff summary:

```bash
diff --git a/pyproject.toml b/pyproject.toml
index a0353d2..d44b8e8 100644
--- a/pyproject.toml
+++ b/pyproject.toml
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 [tool.poetry]
 name = "library-name-here"
-version = "0.3.1"
+version = "0.3.2"
 description = "..."
```

I'm tempted to use something like this, but not sure if it's ok.

```
chore: Bump version to 0.3.2
```

Comment: Probably use a name like "release" instead of "chore" (you could consider any change you make as a chore :-) ). Also consider using `bumpversion` pip package with a `bumpversion.cfg` to automate this change. It can perform version string updates to multiple files in your project, add the commit message for you, and even create git tags.

Comment: Didn't find any `release` type in the URL. So I thought there was probably any convention regarding that type of commits